# ParametricRegion is not showing complete region

Tags: plotting, graphics, regions, geometry, parametric-functions

I am trying to plot a region using the following code

```
reg = ParametricRegion[{{pSG + 5*pGS + 4 pSS, 5*pSG + 4*pSS + pGS}, 
    pSG + pGS + pSS + pGG == 1 && pGS >= pGG >= 0 && pSG >= pGG && 
     pSG >= pSS >= 0 && pGS >= pSS}, {pSG, pGS, pSS, pGG}];
RegionPlot[reg]
```

But for some reason, it is missing some parts. For example, if we consider `pGS=1, pSS=pGG=pSG=0`, we expect the point `(5,1)` to be in the region but it's not.
[image: reg]

I tried tweaking the parameters and writing the conditions differently to see what would happen but it doesn't fix the problem.
Does anyone have an idea what might be going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With hidden `Method` option:

```
 reg = ParametricRegion[{{pSG + 5*pGS + 4 pSS, 5*pSG + 4*pSS + pGS}, 
 pSG + pGS + pSS + pGG == 1 && pGS >= pGG >= 0 && pSG >= pGG && 
 pSG >= pSS >= 0 && pGS >= pSS}, {pSG, pGS, pSS, pGG}];

RegionPlot[reg, Method -> {"DiscretizationMethod" -> "Symbolic"}]
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `DiscretizeRegion[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0001]` to increase the accuracy.

```
reg = ParametricRegion[{{pSG + 5*pGS + 4 pSS, 5*pSG + 4*pSS + pGS}, 
    pSG + pGS + pSS + pGG == 1 && pGS >= pGG >= 0 && pSG >= pGG && 
     pSG >= pSS >= 0 && pGS >= pSS}, {pSG, pGS, pSS, pGG}];
RegionMember[reg, {5, 1}]
dreg=DiscretizeRegion[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0001];
Graphics[{dreg, Red, Point[{5, 1}]}]
RegionPlot[dreg, Epilog -> {Red, Point[{5, 1}]}]
```

> `True`

[image]